# Is the valueStack exposed to EL in a JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, el

We can access the `valueStack` (and other objects of `ActionContext`) using `OGNL` but can we do the same with `EL`. I mean the Action class' properties, for instance, that are exposed via `valueStack`; are they available via EL (are they set as request attributes, only then I guess they will be available). If a class implements `ModelDriven`, we can access the model object's properties via their direct name, instead of using `modelObject.propertyName` in JSPs using OGNL. Can we do the same using EL ?

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/can-we-use-jstl-with-the-framework.html

Comment: Thanks. But is it available with Strut 2.1 ? And it talks about JSTL tags. How can it apply to EL too? And please make it an answer, so that I can try to accept it

Comment: i believe this is available with older version of S2 even.

Comment: @Umesh, If you look at the struts2 tag we have had a great resolution rate recently. Since your answer is the right one, you're the right person to slap it into the answer box. There aren't enough people high enough to close duplicate questions... so without an answer the resolution rate drops... and if you compare say struts2 against spring-mvc, well... we can't slack off ;)

Comment: @Quaternion: Agree!!! and i always want S2 community to as active as possible :)

Comment: While the question has already been answered, wouldn't it have been quicker to just try it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing answer based on the comments so that user with same query/question able to get it answered.

JSTL integration is built into the framework - there are no steps required to enable it. Simply refer to your JSTL expressions just as you would with a normal SAF JSP tag, such as the property tag.

For more details refer to official document

- [can-we-use-jstl-with-the-struts2-framework](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/can-we-use-jstl-with-the-framework.html)